# How to get an array of Names in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am new to discord.js and I am stuck getting the names of all the members of the server. This is the code:

```
**const List = bot.guilds.cache.get("88888952704"); // Getting the guild.
const Members = List.members.map((member) => {
    member.displayName;
});**

//Basic hello
bot.on("message", (msg) => {
    let args = msg.content.slice(Prefix.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
        //For Testing
        case "ping":
            msg.channel.send("Pong!");
            break;
        //Now Serious
        case "info":
            if (args[1] == "version") {
                msg.reply("I am currently at version " + botVersion + "!");
            } else if (args[1] == null) {
                msg.channel.send(
                    "Please be specific about what info you want like: !info version "
                );
            }
            break;
        case "cleartill":
            if (!args[1]) {
                msg.reply("Please be specific: Error 01B%s@1");
            } else {
                msg.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]);
                break;
            }
        case "embed":
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("User Information:")
                .addField("Player Name:", msg.author.username)
                .setColor("#FFFF00")
                .addField("Version:", botVersion);
            msg.channel.send(embed);
            break;
        case "whoisa":
            if (args[1] == null) {
                msg.reply("Please enter the second argument.");
            } else {
                msg.channel.send(Members + " is a " + args[1]);
            }
    }
});
```

I want to get a random name of any person in the server and reply to the person who entered `!whoisa [something]` and give the answer `[something]` is a `[args[1]]`. Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the guild, you can fetch all members using [`members.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch). It returns a collection which has a [`.map()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=map) method, so you can iterate over the collection and return their `displayName` like this:

```js
const guild = bot.guilds.cache.get("824977762186952704");
const members = await guild.members.fetch();

const names = members.map((member) => member.displayName);

// names is an array of names
console.log(names);
```

Collections also have a [`.random()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=random) method that you can use to get a random member from that collection. The returned member is a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/GuildMember), so you can get its display name, send a DM to them, etc.

```js
// randomMember is a guild member
const randomMember = members.random();
```

If you want to use it with your message event, you can even [get the guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Message?scrollTo=guild) from the message. As I'm using `await` here, make sure you add the `async` keyword in `bot.on("message", async (msg) => {`.

```js
case 'whoisa':
  if (!args[1]) 
    return msg.channel.send('Please enter an argument');

  const members = await msg.guild.members.fetch();

  msg.channel.send(`${members.random()} is a ${args.slice(1).join(' ')}`);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a thousand times.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros The link you have provided is broken, please consider fixing it.

Comment: Are you talking about the server ID or what likn?

Comment: I had a comment with a broken link but I've already removed it so you can't see it anymore ;)

Comment: I am getting an error : (node:10116) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [GUILD_MEMBERS_TIMEOUT]: Members didn't arrive in time.

Comment: (node:10116) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)

Comment: Please help if you can.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230453/discussion-between-zsolt-meszaros-and-sheeraz).